# Piping text log to Blue Ocean?

Tags: unity-game-engine, jenkins

I'm using Blue Ocean to do a Unity3D build through command lines (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html).

I currently have a stage in blue ocean which runs the build command in a 'Windows Batch Script' outputting the log to a text file on the computer.

is there a way to also output that same logging text to the blue ocean build output? Right now all I see is the batch command.

Comment: This is not really related to Jenkins.

Comment: Blue ocean is simply an interface on top of jenkins + jenkins-pipelines, it is not the name for the product

Answer (score 1):

You have to make Unity to log to the standard out, then the logs will be picked up by Jenkins. The docs you linked has a -batchmode switch that says `Note that in batch mode, Unity sends a minimal version of its log output to the console. However, the Log Files still contain the full log information.`

I believe running with that flag you will see some output in Jenkins. You can test it locally too. When you run the unity command, if you see output in your command line, chances are high that you will have it in Jenkins too.

Comment: I guess the OP already is using the `-batchmode` flag. But as yourself already cited this will only print minimal output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

I do this simply using `type` to print out the content of my log file in combination with Unity's `-logFile` flag to define a specific location (simply the workspace of the project) So I use e.g.

```
Unity.exe -quit -nographics -batchmode -logFile </path/to/logfile.txt <do stuff>
```

And at the end of the build in the batch file witch does the unity build call I simply added

```
type </path/to/file.txt>
```

so the log gets printed out in the build log.

I prefer this way over the direct redirection to the standart output because I simply have the file itself and can e.g. share it with someone. I also have multiple Unity calls seperaten in different build steps (e.g. import a package; than call a method to build) and they have different logFiles.

---

Of course this solution is **not** in real-time if this is what you're after.